# How to create an instance of typeclass Monad[F[_]] of a custom type constructor in Scala Cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats

How can I create an instance of a custom type constructor in Cats?
I know that cats already comes with almost all Scala built-in type constructors and I can import them by e.g `import cats.data._ import cats.implicits._ import cats.instances._` but I would like to know how can I create my own implicit instance to work with monads operators sintaxs like **>>=** with my own custom type constructor. Suppose I have `MyType[A]` that is monadic o at least has `flatMap` and a `pure` constructor, I want to do things like:

```
Monad[MyType].pure(x) >>= { _.fooBar }
```

I saw at the sources of `instances` package to look at some examples like `Option` but it seems to be a lot to do, I don't know if there is an easy way.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide an implicit instance of Monad for your type, and implement the required methods:

```
implicit object MyMonad extends Monad[MyType] {
  def pure[A](x: A): MyType[A] = ???
  def flatMap[A, B](fa: MyType[A])(f: A => MyType[B]): MyType[B] = ???
  def tailRecM[A, B](a: A)(f: A => MyType[Either[A, B]]): MyType[B] = ???
}
```

If you are confident that your Monad is stack-safe, you can skip implementing `tailRecM` and extend `StackSafeMonad[MyType]` instead.